# Skipping AND when variable IS NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an existing Stored Procedure and i add some parameter to filter the result.But when @id_account is null it returns Empty Data. I want to skip AND when @id_account is null, i try IF condition but it wont work. Any suggestion? Thanks :D

`AND
(
  pd_account.id_account = @id_account
)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put in the condition you really want, which is:

```
(pd_account.id_account = @id_account or @id_account is null)
```

Comment: OMG Thanks.. I tried CASE, IF and many conditional statement inside where clause and this one works :D Thank you so much! Cheers! My procedure works fine and it output the way i want! haha

Comment: @FlashProgrammer . . . I note that you accepted the other answer.  Is there a particular reason?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
AND
(
  pd_account.id_account = COALESCE(@id_account,pd_account.id_account)
)
```

[From COALESCE doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

> Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no
>   non-NULL values.

So when `@id_account` is not provided the condition will be `pd_account.id_account =pd_account.id_account` which is equivalent to `1=1` always true.

You can use CASE like:

```
AND pd_account.id_account = CASE WHEN @id_account IS NOT NULL THEN @id_account
                                 ELSE pd_account.id_account
                            END
```

Comment: this one works too.. but im not familiar in COALESCE. maybe i'll read its documentation about it. Anyway i will also accept your answer after 8mins :D thank you so much